# SQL server timeouts for some commands for a while just after restoring

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

We have a large web application in asp.net mvc using EF6 and SQL server 2012.

We have two environments: staging and production.

Every time we have a release, we first deploy the exact same code to staging and restore production's db on the server for testing purposes.  That has always worked for us.

Now, when we restore production's db to the staging server we are getting some timeouts on some commands.  What's strange is that after a few hours pass, we stop getting timeouts.

---

This is the stacktrace of one of the timeouts:

```
[Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out]

[SqlException (0x80131904): Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The statement has been terminated.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +388
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +688
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4403
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData() +82
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData() +135
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) +6664141
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +6666008
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +577
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +107
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +288
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +180
   Glimpse.Ado.AlternateType.GlimpseDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +847
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(Func`1 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`1 executing, Action`1 executed) +72
   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +306
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues) +417
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() +218

[UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update() +537
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction(Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess) +627
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChangesToStore(SaveOptions options, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy) +212
   System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Func`1 operation) +263
   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.SaveChanges(SaveOptions options) +262
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +218

[DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +291
   *******.Services.DbTransaction.TransactionManager.SaveChanges() in c:\BuildAgent\work\c357fed3de014622\Source\Services\*******.Services\*******.Services\DbTransaction\TransactionManager.cs:28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41() +112
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41() +452
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41() +452
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass48.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__41() +452
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +15
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +37
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +241
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +111
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288
```

We have an action filter that calls the `context.SaveChanges()` method if everything went well on the request (so we don't have to do that manually in every action).  That's why there is no action on the stacktrace, it times out on the `SaveChanges()` call when the action finished.

There is a lot happening on that request, that's why I'm not showing code, we are doing the usual stuff: updating some rows, inserting new ones, etc.  There are some complex commands in there, but not complex enough for the db to timeout.  And when we run the code on our dev machines with the same production db it runs ok.

The weird thing is that it stops timing out after a few hours.  But we can't risk going to production like that.

Now, I know it's unlikely that you can give me a solution just with the information provided.  But I'd like to know some tips, pointers, advice, where to look, what to check, etc.

## Edit

Our server has 12GB of RAM and an Intel Xeon E5-2680 @ 2.80GHz.

Our site is the only thing running there.

Our database is less than 4GB

And we don't get timeout on our dev machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We finally found what was happening:

We have a seed method that was executed after the migration, that method opened a connection to the database and was also querying some external services that took forever to respond, it kept running for hours and those queries were blocking the insert command.

Thanks to [Zdravko's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30330219/sql-server-timeouts-for-some-commands-for-a-while-just-after-restoring#comment48756791_30330365) we were able to find the issue.

We ran `exec sp_who2` and found that the `insert` was being blocked by the seed method's `select` query.

So, if anyone gets here with a similar problem: what helped us was using the sql profiler and filtering for queries taking longer than `30 sec` to find the offending queries and using `exec sp_who2` to check if someone is blocking them.

Answer (score 3):

Timeouts are most likely due to SQL server rebuilding indexes and other maintenance jobs running after the restore. Those can take significant amount of time on a larger database. Full text search indexes for example take particularly long time to build...

Comment: like hours? I mean, last time it was like 6 hours, we even ran `exec sp_updatestats`

Comment: well, it all depends... how big is your db and what else is going on the server (and how powerful the server is in the first place)

Comment: pick up a query that times out and see the execution plan. then wait 6h and check the execution plan again. I bet it will be different, using different indexes the second time.

Comment: how do I know the exact query that is causing the timeout?

Comment: you can run the sql profiler and capture all queries that take longer than say 30 sec. alternatively you can catch the exception from EF and record (for example to the eventlog) the query that triggered the exception.

Comment: Thanks, we found our issue, I posted an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30354540/979293)